# Blog and BlogPosting for Google

Tags: schema.org, blog

Schema.org has [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article), [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) and [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting).

[Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) only uses `Article`.

If I understand `Blog` and `BlogPosting` are types of `Article`. So I suppose it is just a way to be more precise.

I have a blog with a home page with all the titles and a brief summary and then a page with each post. Should I use `Blog` for the blog home page and `BlogPosting` for each post or I should use only `Article`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BlogPosting` is a more specific type of `Article`, but `Blog` isn’t.

`Blog` is for the blog itself. It can make sense to use it only for the homepage of the blog, but it’s also possible to use it for every page of the blog. Wherever you use `Blog`, if the page contains blog posts (or blog post teasers), you can use the [`blogPost`](http://schema.org/blogPost) property to link the `BlogPosting` items.

When you have a blog post, use `BlogPosting`, not `Article`. It’s a best practice to always use the most specific type for your case. Google [mentions this in their technical guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#technical-guidelines), too:

> **Use the most specific applicable type and property names** defined by schema.org for your markup.

Thanks to the type inheritance, conforming consumers will understand that a `BlogPosting` is also a `SocialMediaPosting` and an `Article` and a `CreativeWork` and a `Thing`:

> `Thing` > `CreativeWork` > `Article` > `SocialMediaPosting` > `BlogPosting`

Comment: Why Google Testing Tool only uses Article? (I like it or not, I need to make Google happy, even when they are wrong)

Comment: @Nrc: What makes you think that they only support `Article`? I guess you are talking about their Article rich result, right? [They document](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types): "Non-video objects must be based on one of the following schema.org types: `Article`, `NewsArticle`, `BlogPosting`."

Comment: See the link: https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/

Comment: @Nrc: Sorry, I can’t (accessing the linked page seems to require a login, but I don’t have a Google account).

Comment: This is the Google Testing Tool. A tool that helps to create the markup code. This is a screen shot:
https://www.mig-marketing.com/externs/img/tests/google-testing-tool.png

Comment: @Nrc That's not the testing tool, that's for helping you add markup. Google only provides a limited subset of schemas for that tool to support you adding markup to a page interactively. The testing tool is at https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/, which fully supports the Blog schema alongside many others.