# Which Schema.org type is right, "Blog" or "BlogPosting" for a simple blog article?

Tags: schema.org, blog, json-ld

In reference to the [`Blog` schema](http://schema.org/Blog), do I use `Blog` or `BlogPosting` in the `@type` field?  I've seen examples of both.

The example below passes both Google's structured data test and the [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/).

```json
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Blog",
"headline": "<?=$title;?>",
"url": "<?=$page_url;?>",
"datePublished": "<?=$iso_date_published;?>",
"dateModified": "<?=$iso_date_edited;?>",
"author": "<?=$poster;?>",
"publisher": {
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "News &amp; Opinion"
},
"description": "<?=$j_body;?>"
```

However if I change the `@type` to `BlogPosting`, then I get some errors about not including images etc.

What is the difference between `Blog` and `BlogPosting`?  When would you use either of them?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Blog and BlogPosting for Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/106351/17633). --- Regarding the required `image`, see: [Schema.org BlogPosting and image required](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/83300/17633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing an article in a blog so you should use the *BlogPosting* type, [google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-guidelines) explain it well, you can use the *Blog* type if you are in the homepage of your blog because the structured data refer to the blog and not the article. 
If *BlogPosting* is giving you problem you can use the [*blogPost*](http://schema.org/blogPost) property of *Blog*